# Declaring class object inside switch statement

Tags: c#, visual-c++

This is my first time writing code so complex, and I stumbled onto a problem.
So, I am trying to make a very basic text based RPG, in visual C# using visual studio.
I have 3 forms up until this point. The main menu form (with play and exit buttons), the character selection form (which opens once you click play), and the game form itself. 
On the character selection form, the user is prompted to choose its character class (mage, warrior, rogue). 
I have created a public abstract class called entity:

```
    public abstract class Entity
{
    #region Attributes

    protected string _name;
    protected int _strength, _strengthModifier,
        _magic, _magicModifier,
        _luck, _luckModifier,
        _defense, _defenseModifier,
        _health, _healthModifier;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        protected set { _name = value; }
    }
    public int Strength
    {
        get { return _strength; }
        protected set { _strength = value; }
    }
    public int StrengthModifier
    {
        get { return _strengthModifier; }
        protected set { _strengthModifier = value; }
    }
    public int Magic
    {
        get { return _magic; }
        protected set { _magic = value; }
    }
    public int MagicModifier
    {
        get { return _magicModifier; }
        protected set { _magicModifier = value; }
    }
    public int Luck
    {
        get { return _luck; }
        protected set { _luck = value; }
    }
    public int LuckModifier
    {
        get { return _luckModifier; }
        protected set { _luckModifier = value; }
    }
    public int Defense
    {
        get { return _defense; }
        protected set { _defense = value; }
    }
    public int DefenseModifier
    {
        get { return _defenseModifier; }
        protected set { _defenseModifier = value; }
    }
    public int Health
    {
        get { return _health; }
        protected set { _health = value; }
    }
    public int HealthModifier
    {
        get { return _healthModifier; }
        protected set { _healthModifier = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Entity()
    {
        Name = "";
        Strength = 0;
        Magic = 0;
        Luck = 0;
        Defense = 0;
        Health = 0;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    #endregion

}
```

Then I created warrior class, age class and rogue class with inheritance from this one.

```
class Mage : Entity
{
    public Mage(string name) : base()
    {
        _name = name;

            #region Stats
        _strength = 0;
        _strengthModifier = 0;
        _magic = 10;
        _magicModifier = 3;
        _luck = 3;
        _luckModifier = 0;
        _defense = 5;
        _defenseModifier = 0;
        _health = 100;
        _healthModifier = 0;
            #endregion
    }
}
```

Now, I create the class object itself, on the game form. From the character selection form I call the game form and I send players name and class as parameters.

```
        public Game(string name, string characterClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region CreateCharacter

        switch (characterClass)
        {
            case "Mage":
                {
                    Mage player = new Mage(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Mage.png");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); // show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
            case "Rogue":
                {
                    Rogue player = new Rogue(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Rogue.bmp");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); // show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
            case "Warrior":
                {
                    Warrior player = new Warrior(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Warrior.png");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); //show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
        } 

        #endregion


    }
```

Now. If I try to call player outside of that switch, it wont work. The only solution I can see is to have the code 3 times, once in each case. I am, anyway, 1000% sure that is not the way.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The variables are local to the switch case. Once outside the switch they are automatically destroyed. If you want to use them outside the switch you need to declare them outside the switch

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you instantiate the objects in a local brush, that is, you will not be able to access them from outside the switch. If you want to use them outside the switch you need to declare them outside the switch. Like this:

```
public Game(string name, string characterClass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region CreateCharacter

        Entity player = null;
        switch (characterClass)
        {
            case "Mage":
                {
                    player = new Mage(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Mage.png");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); // show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
            case "Rogue":
                {
                    player = new Rogue(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Rogue.bmp");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); // show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
            case "Warrior":
                {
                    player = new Warrior(name); // create player

                    #region PrintPicture

                    pbPlayer.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/mircea/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/RPG/Artwork/Characters/Warrior.png");
                    pbPlayer.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                    pbPlayer.Size = new Size(145, 200);

                    #endregion

                    lblName.Text = player.Name.ToString(); //show player name
                    txtLog.Text += "Welcome to game title, " + name + "!"; // greet log
                    break;
                }
        } 

        #endregion


    }
```

I just put the player's statement up on the switch with abstract type.

By declaring the object before the switch you will be able to access it in and out of it. Since all objects inherit from entity, and entity is an abstract class, you can use it to type objects.

It's the best way I see to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi! I tried that and I still get an error. It says "A local or parameter named 'player' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter", and it says that for every "player" (mage, rogue, warrior) inside the switch

Comment: This is work fine for me. But remember, all the types need to extends Entity. Can you put the Rogue and Warrior class?

Comment: I would like to see the Game class also. I think you forget to remove the types before the `player` variable. You must put the variable's type in the declaration above the switch.